# Remaining volume percentage of a sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

Circular tunnel of radius $r$ is punctured through the center of a homogeneous sphere of radius $R, (r<R)$. What percentage of a sphere is lost? What should be the value of $r$ such that the sphere maintains exactly the half of it's volume?

**Attempt:**

Total volume of a sphere is given by $V_s=\frac{4}{3}\pi R^3$.

Volume of circular tunnel (cylinder) of radius $r$ and height $2r$ is given by $V_c=2r^3\pi$.

To find the percentage $x$ that is lost we solve the equation $$x=\frac{100V_c}{V_s}\Rightarrow x=\frac{150r^3}{R^3}.$$

To find the value of $r$ such that the sphere maintains exactly the half of it's volume we solve the following equation for $r$:
$$2r^3\pi=\frac{2R^3\pi}{3}\Rightarrow r=\frac{R}{\sqrt[3]{3}}.$$

**Question:** Is this correct?

**Note**: I have been suggested to solve the problem using integration, but I don't know how to apply it here. Could someone explain?

**EDIT**:

Percentage of the volume that is lost is given by
$$x=\frac{150\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right(r^2-R^2)(\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-3R)-\pi r^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2})}{\pi R^3}$$

To find the value of $r$ such that the sphere maintains exactly the half of it's volume, we solve the equation for $r$:

$$V_{remaining}=\frac{1}{2}V_{total}$$

where

$$V_{remaining}=V_{total}-2\left(\frac{\pi}{3}(r^2-R^2)(\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-3R)-2\pi r^2\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right)$$

and

$$V_{total}=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}$$

After simplifying the above equation,

$$r^2(11\pi R^4-9R^4r^2+24\pi^2 R^2 r^2-8\pi^2 R^4-16\pi^2 r^4)=3\pi^2 R^6$$

**Question:** How to solve this equation for $r$?

Comment: This is a classical example, known as the [Napkin ring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napkin_ring_problem).

Comment: Your equation for the tunnel volume is not correct.  The length is a little less than $R$, not $r$, and you need to account for the [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) on each end.